# Hasura returning duplicates items for some entries

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have a this graphql query on hasura

```
query MyQuery {
  events(where: {event_id: {_eq: "6b1a8373"}}) {
    checkins {
      checkpoint {
        name
      }
      created_at
      user {
        email
        first_name
        last_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it returns duplicate items for some entries. What could be causing the problem? How can I fix it?

This is what is being returned

```
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "checkins": [
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Vaccari Italian Restaurant"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Vaccari Italian Restaurant"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Silver Lake Pool & Inn"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Silver Lake Pool & Inn"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "USC Hotel"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Vaccari Italian Restaurant"
            }
          },
          {
            "checkpoint": {
              "name": "Vaccari Italian Restaurant"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There should only be 2 "Vaccari Italian Restaurant" and 2 "Silver Lake Pool & Inn"

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized example response?

Comment: Take a look at database level. What will return on `SELECT * from events E JOIN checkins C ON [what defined in array relationships]` ?

Comment: At the database level, it returns the expected result. The Hasura graphql query is what' returning the duplicates.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL for the above query?

Comment: I think I found the problem, there was an array relationship, when it should have been an object relationship. I think that's what was causing the issue. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @phatnael - Can you add the solution and mark it as answered to make it easy for anyone in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I was defining my relationships I created an array relationship where it should have been an object relationship. Once I changed it to object relationship, it is working properly as intended.